# Why do mem_load_retired.l1_hit and mem_load_retired.l1_miss not add to the total number of loads?

Tags: caching, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, perf

I'm investigating the effects of cache on performance on x86-64 CPUs. I've been using Linux's perf to monitor cache hit/miss rates, particularly these counters:

- `mem_inst_retired.all_loads`
- `mem_load_retired.l1_hit`
- `mem_load_retired.l1_miss`

I expect that `all_loads ~= l1_hit + l1_miss`, because a load instruction can either hit or miss the L1 cache - no other option, because all regular loads go through the cache. I have read the Intel documentation [here](https://perfmon-events.intel.com/) which doesn't say much and nothing that would disprove my thinking, as far as I can tell.

However, when running certain code, I notice that the sum is far below `all_loads`.
For example, the following assembly, which sums 1 billion memory locations with stride 32B:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl main
main:
    sub     rsp, 8     # Stack alignment for call
    push    r12
    push    r13
    mov     r12, 0xfffffff     # Array size

    mov     rdi, r12
    call    malloc              # Allocate array
    mov     r13, rax          # Save array pointer

    mov     rdi, r13          # Write to array to force page-in
    mov     rsi, 42
    mov     rdx, r12
    call    memset

    mov     rcx, 1000000000    # Loop counter
    mov     rdx, 0             # Index sequence start
    mov     rax, 0             # Result accumulator

.p2align 4      # Skylake JCC alignment issue
loop:
    mov     rdi, rdx
    and     rdi, r12      # Mask index to array size
    movzx   rsi, BYTE PTR [r13+rdi]   # Read from array index
    add     rax, rsi

    lea     rdx, [rdx+32] # Generate next array index
    dec     rcx        # Loop counter & condiiton
    jnz     loop

    pop     r13
    pop     r12
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

It yields the following perf results:

```
~$ perf stat -e instructions,cycles,mem_inst_retired.all_loads,mem_load_retired.l1_hit,mem_load_retired.l1_miss ./test

 Performance counter stats for './test':

     7,000,215,742      instructions:u                   #    1.25  insn per cycle            
     5,589,048,737      cycles:u                                                              
       998,622,922      mem_inst_retired.all_loads:u                                          
        17,215,080      mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u                                             
       424,118,595      mem_load_retired.l1_miss:u                                            

       1.939187022 seconds time elapsed

       1.826889000 seconds user
       0.112177000 seconds sys
```

`all_loads` is approximately 1 billion as expected (albeit a little lower, maybe some sampling artefact though). However `l1_hit + l1_miss` is about 450 million - seems like ~50% of loads have gone unaccounted for.

**What is causing `l1_hit` and `l1_miss` to not sum to `all_loads`?**

Interestingly, if the memory load stride is varied such that almost all loads are hits or misses, the results tend towards `all_loads ~= l1_hit + l1_miss`. It is only in the middle ground where the equality breaks down.

EDIT: I tested this on two CPUs: a Kaby Lake, and an Ice Lake. Both showed the same results.

Comment: Separate from your question, this appears to be Intel syntax, but you still have the `%` decorators on register names from AT&T?  Either use `.intel_syntax noprefix` and write instructions like `lea   rdx, [rdx+32]` (or better `add rdx, 32`), or use AT&T syntax.  Clang's assembler won't even accept this painful to read mutant hybrid.

Comment: I'm using GCC and struggled to get it to accept Intel syntax - this is what I ended up with. Good to know about the noprefix thing, I'll try that.

Comment: Since you are hitting each cache line twice is it possible that the second load will find that line still being fetched (i.e. the LFB still in use) and thus it's not a miss because it already missed and won't allocate a new LFB but it's also not a hit because it's not yet in the cache? Maybe it's a bug in how the performance counters are actually incremented, one that Intel doesn't consider worth fixing?

Comment: @MargaretBloom a possible theory on the LFB - although in that case surely Intel would say so in the docs? Also, from my understanding, your theory should hold if we vary the number of hits per line. But if you lower the stride in the code, the hit counter will quickly approach 1 billion.

Comment: @MargaretBloom In terms of a bug, I'll see if I can run it on another machine. The CPU I was testing was several years old.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Good point, LFB hit would be a third possibility if it doesn't also get counted as an L1d miss.  (You often wouldn't want it to, if you want to know how many instructions result in a new request to L2.)  Is `mem_inst_retired.all_stores` nearly equal to `mem_load_retired.fb_hit + mem_load_retired.l1_hit + mem_load_retired.l1_miss`?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I tried it on my own Skylake system (with EPP=balance-performance, so it ended up running at 2.7GHz).  With `perf stat --no-big-num --all-user -e ...`, I got hit+miss+LFB = 994.188M vs. all-loads = 999.958M counts.  So the sum is low by 0.58%.  On repeated runs, this is pretty typical, the sum of the miss/hit/LFB counters being a small fraction lower than `mem_inst_retired.all_loads`.

Comment: MCΔT, @PeterCordes Thanks for your testing. I don't know what causes these discrepancies. My  only hypothesis is that either the prefetchers (which should be affected by the stride) are involved in some subtle way or the LFB has some form of Early-termination so that it can serve data that hit in the partial line read so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As Margaret Bloom pointed out in comments, loads to the same cache line as an already-outstanding cache line can "hit" in that LFB**, instead of allocating a new one.  Turns out, that counts a neither a `l1_hit` nor `l1_miss`.  And there's a separate event for it, `mem_load_retired.fb_hit`.   (It's probably good that `l1_miss` only counts instructions that result in a new request to L2, rather than counting LFB hits as both.  Also note that LFBs can be occupied by outgoing stores, including NT stores, so an LFB hit due to that is also possible; it's not always just due to multiple loads.)

**Your code strides by 32 bytes, so does 2 loads per 64-byte line; the second one will usually be an LFB hit**.  (The first one might also be an LFB hit if hardware prefetching has already requested it, this probably explains having more LFB hits than misses.)

On my Skylake i7-6700k with this test program, `mem_inst_retired.all_loads` is only greater than `mem_load_retired.fb_hit + mem_load_retired.l1_hit + mem_load_retired.l1_miss` by about 0.6%.

So there's still a bit of a mystery of what the difference is, what's counted by `mem_inst_retired.all_loads` but not any of the three more specific counters.  I'd have expected them to be closer to exactly equal, especially with `--all-user` or the `:u` events so there isn't noise<sup>1</sup> while counters are being programmed or collected.

With `perf stat --no-big-num --all-user -e ...` for easy copy/paste of the numbers into `calc`, I got hit+miss+LFB = 994.188M vs. all-loads = 999.958M counts in one run. So the sum is low by 0.58%. On repeated runs, this is pretty typical, the sum of the miss/hit/LFB counters being a small fraction lower than mem_inst_retired.all_loads.

A couple more runs:

```
$ perf stat --all-user --no-big-num -e task-clock,page-faults,instructions,cycles,mem_inst_retired.all_loads,mem_load_retired.l1_hit,mem_load_retired.l1_miss,mem_load_retired.fb_hit ./a.out

 Performance counter stats for './a.out':

           1673.21 msec task-clock                       #    0.997 CPUs utilized             
               183      page-faults                      #  109.371 /sec                      
        7000141672      instructions                     #    1.56  insn per cycle            
        4475942186      cycles                           #    2.675 GHz                       
         999892622      mem_inst_retired.all_loads       #  597.590 M/sec                     
          10563966      mem_load_retired.l1_hit          #    6.314 M/sec                     
         449822478      mem_load_retired.l1_miss         #  268.838 M/sec                     
         533816318      mem_load_retired.fb_hit          #  319.038 M/sec                     

       1.677680356 seconds time elapsed

       1.647640000 seconds user
       0.023197000 seconds sys


$ perf stat --all-user --no-big-num -e task-clock,page-faults,instructions,cycles,mem_inst_retired.all_loads,mem_load_retired.l1_hit,mem_load_retired.l1_miss,mem_load_retired.fb_hit ./a.out

 Performance counter stats for './a.out':

           1649.17 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
               182      page-faults                      #  110.359 /sec                      
        7000141486      instructions                     #    1.58  insn per cycle            
        4419739785      cycles                           #    2.680 GHz                       
         999850616      mem_inst_retired.all_loads       #  606.275 M/sec                     
           9372903      mem_load_retired.l1_hit          #    5.683 M/sec                     
         450146459      mem_load_retired.l1_miss         #  272.953 M/sec                     
         534244404      mem_load_retired.fb_hit          #  323.947 M/sec                     

       1.649504255 seconds time elapsed

       1.634275000 seconds user
       0.013270000 seconds sys
```

(I normally run single-threaded tests under `taskset -c 1` to ensure no `cpu-migration` events, but that typically doesn't happen anyway for short runs on an idle system.)

My EPP `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference`) settings is `balance-performance` (not full `performance`), so hardware P-state management clocked down to 2.7GHz on this memory-bound workload.  The calculated 2.68GHz only counts user-space cycles because of `--all-user`, but `task-clock` is wall-clock time. (This somewhat reduces per-core memory bandwidth since the uncore slows down, making latency x max_in-flight_lines a limiting factor in single-core memory bandwidth.  This isn't a problem for this experiment, but it's something else non-obvious that's visible in this perf data.  My i7-6700k has dual channel DDR4-2666, running Arch Linux, kernel 6.4.9)

**Footnote 1: even `--all-user` isn't perfect**.  @John McCalpin commented:

> The details vary by implementation, but there are lots and lots of little gotchas when trying to make performance counts accurate in the presence of unnecessary user/kernel crossings. Ice Lake Xeon will undercount if the counters are configured for user-only or kernel-only (errata ICX14). Going through the kernel is OK for coarse measurements (~10%), but **for detailed studies of the consistency of different events it is best to avoid leaving user-space.**

You'd do this by collecting counts in user-space via `rdpmc`, after getting the kernel to program the counters.  (Perhaps via `perf_event_open`.)

Avoiding interrupts on that core could be done via short test intervals, otherwise you'd want to look into `isolcpus=` Linux kernel boot options so you can test for longer than a timeslice while still avoiding any user/kernel transitions during the timed / profiled region.

Comment: A well-explained answer, thank you. And also thanks to Margaret Bloom. I can confirm that I see the same results with `mem_load_retired.fb_hit` on my machine.

Comment: You can often get closer to expected values by using inline reads of the performance counters (RDPMC) on a thread that is pinned to a specific logical processors.  (This also reduces the overhead of each counter read from >2000 cycles to about 25 cycles.).  For a wide variety of complex implementation issues it is unusual to get exact matches to expected values for anything that involves the caches, but deviations in the 0.6% range like those here should not get in the way of understanding performance issues.

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: I normally do run single-threaded tests with `taskset -c 1 perf stat ...`, so indeed it was pinned to a specific logical processor.  I didn't mention that in the answer but I think I did that here.  I did omit the `cpu-migrations` event from my usual `perf stat` command line to reduce clutter.

Comment: I'd hoped `--all-user` (to only count user-space events, like `:u` on each of them) would be at least as good for having them match as collecting counters in user-space, and in fact might help since it lets the dust settle on loads done by user-space before the kernel code collects counters.  Oh, but with entering the kernel on an interrupt not being fully serializing (or is that just `syscall`), maybe some events go uncounted due to that, or get missed during the switch.

Comment: @PeterCordes The details vary by implementation, but there are lots and lots of little gotchas when trying to make performance counts accurate in the presence of unnecessary user/kernel crossings.  Ice Lake Xeon will undercount if the counters are configured for user-only or kernel-only (errata ICX14).  Going through the kernel is OK for coarse measurements  (~10%), but for detailed studies of the consistency of different events it is best to avoid leaving user-space.