# If I run the same program multiple times will it precisely take same number of clock cycles?

Tags: c, windows, performance, assembly, intel

Sorry for not being specific with the problem,
I need a way to calculate the exact number of clock cycles my algorithm takes, written in C,

-> I tried clock() and windows specific functions like QueryPerformanceCounter(),
None of them gave me exact clock cycles on each run.

I'm getting completely different values on each run FOR THE SAME INPUT.

**If you suggest any ways to find execution time in terms of clock cycles, that won't change on each run, that'll be really helpful.**

Hardware: mine is intel i5 processor and running under windows 10 OS.

Comment: "_the exact number of clock cycles my algorithm takes_": This number doesn't exist. It will not be the exact same on every run of the program and it certainly depends on much more than the algorithm.

Comment: You won't be able to find an exact number in this context. Too many variables outside the scope of your program. The closest you can probably achieve is by [clocking the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c) at the start of your program and subtracting it from the time at the end of your program. With a bunch of runs, you can get an average execution time in milliseconds.

Comment: Your program will always have the exact same instructions that will run. But the programs actual run-time might differ from run to run, because it has to compete for the system resources with all other processes running on the same system.

Comment: @Hari "completely different values" --> what are some of those values?

Comment: QPC doesn't measure clock cycles at all, it measures time. Time is even more variable than clock cycles.

Comment: Are you always starting the program with the disk heads in exactly the same position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are running your program on a very primitive processor with no operating system nor device driver interference, there is no such thing as *the exact number of clock cycles your algorithm takes*. Running on Windows 10 on an i5 processor absolutely does not qualify.

The time your program takes to execute and even the number of clocks depends on a myriad of factors that make it non predictable in a substantial part:

- the program may issue operating system calls to retrieve input or produce output: the operating system may execute different code for these calls in different runs, leading to different times.
- the program may have undefined or implementation defined behavior leading to non predictive execution paths, even if these do not seem to affect the results.
- modern processors have memory caches that make memory accesses depend on previous accesses, including those that happened before your program executes.
- the program may be interrupted by the operating system to handle device requests or other tasks that will interfere with your program timings and clock cycle counts, among other side effects such as cache flushing.
- modern processors use branch prediction and/or speculative execution, which is a form of instruction cacheing that affect the cycle count in substantial ways and is typically non reproducible.
- the hardware may interfere too: depending on CPU temperature, the clock speed and/or CPU voltage may be adjusted by the motherboard, affecting the run times and possibly the clock counts.
- recent CPUs may even include non predictive adjustments for instructions that read the clock counts or use some other precise timing measurements in order to prevent [side channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) that rely on clock measurements to determine protected memory contents.

Precise timings of selected program fragments are still possible but not down the the clock count and require advanced skills to try and prevent interference from the above issues and others.  Repeating short tests a large number of times and keeping the best times is a good start, but will always include some range of uncertainty, so with limited accuracy.

More important aspects of the algorithm must be studied: time and space complexity, best, average and worst case scenarios, and above all, **correctness** and range limitations.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of factor effecting my clock ticks than I expected :( Will the rate of clock speed directly affect the number of ticks a program takes ? I think only wall time will be affected?

Comment: @Hari: the clock speed may affect the clock count of some instructions, and the instruction pipeline and cache behavior too.  You really should not make any assumptions and use the wall clock time for your benchmarks.  Dissecting low level timings has become a black art well beyond most programmers' skill level, including mine. I used to successfully predict and hand optimize assembly code in the 80s and 90s, became an avid user of [Agner Fog optimisation resources](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) but this game has become vain and futile today.

Comment: Even it's vain and futile at the industry, it's still a mystery for me.. I mean the working of computers at low level

Comment: @Hari: low level is a simplification: the compiler generates assembly or more precisely CPU instructions for the target architecture (note however that even this is a simplification as clang generates LLVM intermediary code that itself gets converted to CPU instructions after a heavy optimisation process.  The CPU reads these instructions and converts them internally into micro-ops which get scheduled through complex pipelines with cache look ahead, branch prediction, speculative execution, register renaming, etc. CPU inner workings have evolved tremendously over the last 4 decades.

Comment: The precise details are a mystery to the vast majority of programmers!  Don't feel bad about it, you can look at the compiler generated assembly on godbolt.org a fine framework that is very useful to investigate code generation, but be aware that you are only scratching the surface of an amazing world with many lower levels of mysterious and complex intricacies.

Comment: @Hari: A different clock speed won't *directly* affect how many core clock cycles it takes to run the same machine code.  (It will affect how many RDTSC ticks it takes, because the reference clock is a fixed frequency independent of the core clock, so it's effectively wall-time in disguise since it doesn't even pause when the core clock does to change voltage/frequency.)

Comment: @Hari:  But since memory frequency stays fixed, a lower CPU clock means L3 cache misses (to DRAM) take fewer core clock cycles, so there's an *indirect* effect from core frequency, less memory latency for OoO exec to hide.  Or on CPUs where the uncore frequency stays high even if one core clocks down, any off-core accesses become relatively faster in core clocks, including L2 misses that hit in L3.  And thus also inter-thread latency in a multithreaded program.

Comment: @Hari: please meet the master :)

Comment: @Hari: BTW, to actually measure core clock cycles, you need something that uses hardware performance counters.  Perhaps VTune on Windows?  Under Linux, `perf stat ----all-user ./a.out` works to count in user-space only.  It's still definitely not reproducible down to the cycle, but it is for counts like instructions retired and branches taken.  related: [How do I determine the number of x86 machine instructions executed in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54355631), and an [example of counting cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342) in a question about mov-elimination.

Comment: Also related: [Why do mem\_load\_retired.l1\_hit and mem\_load\_retired.l1\_miss not add to the total number of loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77052435) - see Dr. John McCalpin's comments about getting consistent measurements being super tricky.  Some people look up to me as an expert; I look up to Dr. Bandwidth's experience and expertise!  He knows a lot about CPU architecture, and has lots of practical experience of many generations of Xeons with using performance counters to analyze stuff.

Comment: @Hari: More background basics: [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) - RDTSC is just glorified wall-clock time.  [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391) - possible for simple loops whose memory accesses hit in cache, otherwise just measure.  chqrlie is right that caches and branch prediction will result in execution times varying from run to run, plus system effects like OS caching speeding up syscalls.